Determine a function $g(x)$ to maximize a definite integral in the form of $\int^{+\infty}_{t} x g(x)f(x) \mathrm dx$
Suppose I have a random variable $X \sim N(0, \sigma^{2})$ with density function $f(x)$. I have another function $g(x) > 0$ defined on $(t, +\infty)$, where $t > 1$ is a constant, and $\int^{+\infty}_{t} g(x) \mathrm dx = 1$.
The question is, suppose my objective function is a definite integral in the form of:
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{t} x g(x)f(x) \mathrm dx.
$$
Then how can I determine $g(x)$ to maximize the above objective function?

There is no maximizer $g$.
If $\sigma> t$ then the maximizer of $xf(x)$ on the interval $[t,\infty)$ is $x=\sigma$. Then you can get your objective function to converge to its maximum of $xf(x)$ by setting
$$g_n(x) = \begin{cases}
n/2 &\text{ if } x\in [\sigma-1/n, \sigma+1/n]\\
0&\text{ otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
where we assume $n$ is large enough that $g$ is restricted to the correct domain.
If $\sigma\leq t$ then the same argument holds but now $xf(x)$ is maximized at $x=t$ and we now define
$$g_n(x) = \begin{cases}
n &\text{ if } x\in [t+1/n,t+2/n]\\
0&\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
you can make the $g_n$s strictly positive in the above examples by replacing each $g_n$ with
$$h_n(x)= (1-1/n)g_n(x) + u(x)/n$$
where $u$ is an arbitrary bounded strictly positive function such that $\int_t^{\infty} u(x)dx=1.$ Then the objective function still converges to its maximum if applied to $h_n$ and setting $n\to\infty$.
Either way, the maximum cannot be achieved by any function $g$. If you are familiar with distributions, then setting $g$ to be the Dirac delta mass at $\max\{\sigma, t\}$ gives you the maximum.
Edit: Fixed the mistake pointed out by @NN2 in the comments.

The maxium of $xf(x)$ is reached when $x = \sigma$!

Oops, you are right.

I gave you +1 but the max is reached really when $x = \sigma$!

Yes you are right. That’s what I get for trying to do this in my head.
